# Docker Desktop: How to make it exit completely?

Tags: kubuntu, systemd, docker, qemu

**Question**: How do I make Docker Desktop and all of its associated processes exit on command?

**Context**:

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 and using Docker Desktop for some local development.
When I close Docker Desktop I would like it and all of its associated processes to exit. However, some of its associated processes continue to run in the background consuming upwards of 8GB of RAM. (qemu-system-x86_64 consumes 8GB all by itself)

`systemctl` commands don't seem to have any effect.

I have been unable to kill qemu-system-x86_64. It respawns.

Rebooting my system does make it all go away. But I would prefer to not have to do that every time.

[screenshot of system monitor - docker processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/038JP.png)

[screenshot of system monitor - qemu-system-x86_64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sGf.png)

[image: screenshots of system monitor]

Comment: Are those processes owned by your user account or do they run under `root`? Docker Desktop does tend to keep a few things running in the background as services if the daemon is running (even if no containers are active) to speed up the next application start 

Comment: All of them are owned by $USER